# Trying to return sec, min, hour as choosable "datetime.datetime" with yield

Tags: python, yield, timedelta

I want to use timedelta with yield, here is my script:

```
def date_range(start_date,count_type):

    time_values = {"hour": 60 * 60, "minute": 60, "second": 1}

    increment_value = time_values[count_type]

    while True:
        yield start_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=increment_value)

no=list(date_range(datetime.datetime(2020,4,28),"second"))

for z in no:

    print(no)
```

When I run the script, I don't get any answer from the run terminal, do you know why?

Edit:
After waiting a while, I got this as answer

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/U----/Desktop/countertypefunc.py", line 197, in <module>
    no=list(date_range(datetime.datetime(2020,4,28),"second"))
MemoryError
```

Comment: what is it you want to achieve? right now, your `while` loop runs indefinitely which is why you get a memory exception at some point when you cast the generator to a list.

Comment: I want to create a count function that counts second, minute, or hour according to choice. it will start to count from a specific time as start_date. Normally without using generator, I was adding the numbers that in time_values into timedelta(seconds=i), and it was working. But when I use generator I am having errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get the question right - what you want is a generator that yields dates (`datetime` objects) within a certain range and with a certain increment between each consecutive date.

The problem is that you create an infinite `generator` by the `while True`. That means that if you try to cast it to a `list`, you get a memory exception since lists are not infinite...

What you could do is introduce an `end_date` (where to stop) and replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop which iterates over all increments that should be done:

```
import datetime

def date_range(start_date, end_date, count_type="second"):
    # determine the increment
    time_values = {"hour": 60 * 60, "minute": 60, "second": 1}
    incr = time_values[count_type]
    # determine the number of iterations / increments to be done
    n = int((end_date-start_date).total_seconds()) // incr
    # iterate...
    for i in range(n):
        yield start_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=incr*i)


t0, t1 = datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 28), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 29)

for d in date_range(t0, t1, "hour"):
    print(d)

# prints
# 2020-04-28 00:00:00
# 2020-04-28 01:00:00
# 2020-04-28 02:00:00
# ...
# 2020-04-28 21:00:00
# 2020-04-28 22:00:00
# 2020-04-28 23:00:00
```

Since you use `yield`, each iteration of the `for` loop will only be executed when you call for the next element of the generator.

You could also use a `while True`, e.g.

```
def date_range2(start_date, count_type="second"):
    time_values = {"hour": 60 * 60, "minute": 60, "second": 1}
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield start_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_values[count_type]*i)

t0 = datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 28)
f = date_range2(t0)
for i in range(10):
    print(next(f))

# prints
# 2020-04-28 00:00:01
# 2020-04-28 00:00:02
# 2020-04-28 00:00:03
# ...
# 2020-04-28 00:00:08
# 2020-04-28 00:00:09
# 2020-04-28 00:00:10
```

...but be careful when using this function. You have to use `next()` to get the next element from the `generator` - if you try to `list(f)`, you run into the `while True` trap again.

Comment: without specifying an "end_date", code is what I wanted to write. how we could do that without end_date? I think we would need a "while" in this case.